Polarization in nonlinear optics
I've very recently started learning nonlinear optics by reading the well-known textbook by Robert W. Boyd (3rd ed.). I don't find the book an excellent choice for self-study. The fundamental concepts are not defined and described clearly, causing confusion and headache!
In Sec. 1.2.2., it reads

Let us next consider the circumstance in which the optical field incident upon
a second-order nonlinear optical medium consists of two distinct frequency
components, which we represent in the form

$$\tilde{E}(t)=E_1e^{-i\omega_1 t}+E_2e^{-i\omega_2 t}+\text{c.c.}$$
Then it is assumed that the "second-order contribution to the nonlinear polarization" is of the form
$$\tilde{P}^{(2)}(t)=\epsilon_0\chi^{(2)}\tilde{E}(t)^2$$
(I think this relation is for a dispersionless, lossless isotropic medium.)
But as far as I know, the equation above (constitutive equation) states the relation between the second-order polarization and the electric field inside the nonlinear medium, not the incident electric field. The amplitudes of the two sine waves are different inside the medium compared to outside the medium. Also sine waves of other frequencies (SHG, DFG, SFG, etc.) are present inside the medium. Don't these other frequencies cause responses (i.e. polarization) of their own?
In other words, aren't these the correct relations?
$$\tilde{E}(t)=E^{\prime}_1e^{-i\omega_1 t}+E'_2e^{-i\omega_2 t}+E_3e^{-i(\omega_1+\omega_2)t}+E_4e^{-i(\omega_1-\omega_2)t}+\cdots+\text{c.c.}$$
and
$$\tilde{P}^{(2)}(t)=\epsilon_0\chi^{(2)}\tilde{E}(t)^2$$

I agree, the electric field in the definition of the second-order polarization $P^{(2)}$ should be the total electric field. This seems to be due to sloppy writing, but I have not read the book.

The initial electric field (at the boundary) is the incident electric field. The field further inside the medium is obtained by solving the dynamics, specifically the nonlinear wave equation (this is covered in ch. 2). In your example, $E_3$ is initially zero, and the whole problem is to calculate its evolution. As for the scaling of the amplitude, that's taken care of by the susceptibility tensor.
